# wget ftp one folder to another folder

Tags: ftp, wget

I'm setting up a shopping cart site for a client. His drop shipper provides an ftp login to download all of the product images. I was going to use wget with mirror option to grab the files and folders and set cron to run once a week as they update their images regularly.

```
wget -nH -m -P /localdirectory/data ftp://name:pass@server/path
```

Unfortunately one of their directories is the pound sign: '#'.  While it transfers correctly, the shopping cart can't find any of the images in that folder because of the # sign.

Remote File Structure:

/Images/#/342image.jpg
/Images/A/aimage.jpg
/Images/B/bimage.jpg
etc...

Is there a way with wget to still grab all folders/files and have an if statement to put files in the '#' folder into a different named folder, such as '5' locally?